# Libgdx change the image inside table dynamically

Tags: libgdx, textures, rendering, image

I am trying to draw a HUD that shows the score and time and image like loading but I want to update and change the image when the score get higher but I tried to do that but it is not working. I thought maybe I can define new table in the update method and put different image each time but I don't want to define new table each time. is there anyway to update the image only inside the table: this is the code:

```
public class Hud implements Disposable{

        public Stage stage;
        private Viewport viewport;
        private static Integer worldTimer;
        private float timecount;
        private static Integer score;
        Label countdownLabel;
        private static Label scorelabel;
        private Label timelabel;
        private Label levellabel;
        private Label worldlabel;
        private Label mariolabel;
        private Image loading;
        private Table table;
        public Hud(SpriteBatch sb)
        {
            worldTimer=40;
            timecount=0;
            score=0;
            viewport=new FitViewport(Fruits.V_WIDTH,Fruits.V_HIEGT,new OrthographicCamera());//2
            stage=new Stage(viewport,sb);//stage is as box and try to put widget and organize things inside that table
            table = new Table();
            table.top();//table at top of our stage
            table.setFillParent(true);//table is now fill all the stage
            countdownLabel=new Label(String.format("%02d",worldTimer),new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.BLACK));//label for gdx
            scorelabel=new Label(String.format("%02d",score),new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.BLACK));//label for gdx
            timelabel=new Label("TIME",new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.BLACK));//label for gdx
            levellabel=new Label("1-1",new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.BLACK));//label for gdx
            worldlabel=new Label("WORLD",new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.BLACK));//label for gdx
            mariolabel=new Label("Score"    ,new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.BLACK));//label for gdx
            loading = new Image(new Texture("10%.png"));
            //loading.setSize(40, 10);
            table.add(mariolabel).expandX().padTop(10);

            table.add(timelabel).expandX().padTop(10);
            table.add(worldlabel).expandX().padTop(10);
            table.row();
            table.add(scorelabel).expandX();

            table.add(countdownLabel).expandX();
            table.add(loading).width(50).height(10);

            stage.addActor(table);

        }
        public void update(float dt)
        {
            timecount+=dt;
            if (timecount>1)
            {
                worldTimer--;
                if(worldTimer>=0) {
                    countdownLabel.setText(String.format("%02d", worldTimer));
                    loading=new Image(new Texture("90.png"));
                }
                timecount=0;

            }
        }
        public static int getTime()
        {

            return worldTimer;
        }

        public static void addScore(int value)
        {
            score +=value;
            scorelabel.setText(String.format("%02d",score));
        }
        public static int getScore()
        {
            return score;
        }
        @Override
        public void dispose() {
            stage.dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the image using `setDrawable()` method:

```java
loading.setDrawable(new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("90.png")));
```